# Maven Dependencies showing outside maven folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Came in the morning fired up eclipse and noticed that eclipse is showing my dependency jars outside the maven dependencies folder. This is a long running workspace and nothing has changed that I am aware of that should cause this behavior.

What's more odd is that the Maven Dependencies folder also has the jars in it as well.

[image]

**I have tried:**

`mvn eclipse:clean` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which did not work as expected because after this only the parent projects showed as maven folders.

Removed the old workspace and recreated which results in the exact same issue.

Verified maven settings and my poms are good. Which should be.

Comment: Don't use image links better post messages text into question. Furthermore do not use `eclise:clean`,  `eclise:eclipse` anymore use M2E instead....

Comment: If you go to your build path properties of project salesauth-model-dto, what do you see under Libraries? You'll probably see the jars under maven dependencies, but you'll also see an entry per jar. Can you check if maven generates this after you do an mvn eclipse:eclipse (directly in the by maven generated .classpath file)? Or is this something that Eclipse later adds?

Comment: @khmarbaise I cannot post this text? The image shows what I am seeing... Also, I am using what I have by the powers that be.

Comment: @RensGroenveld It looks like it is the first instance. I came up with a solution though. Not my favorite but I can post an answer here momentarily.

Comment: This shows that you are not using M2E which causes the issue. You should use M2E which means first remove `.settings`, `.classpath`, `.project`from your project folders afterwards import the root level of your project via Eclipse -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some generated files got hosed up. Still not sure what caused the issue...

My solution was to close eclipse, delete the workspace and in the SVN repo made sure all my work was committed.

Right Clicked > Svn option > Revert on an empty screen.

In the gui there was a `delete un-revisioned files` check box.

This was essentially to get rid of all the maven/eclipse generated files but the target folders go too.

Re-created the workspace imported my maven projects and all cleared up.

Comment: Using the `maven-eclipse-plugin` will hose your setup as mentioned by @khmarbaise above.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have experimented this situation in which the libraries are shown directly within the project's contents is by meeting these two conditions:

- The libraries are specifically set into the `libraries` tab of the `Java Build Project` window.
- The `Libraries from external` option is unchecked (from the `Customize view` option in the project's view menu).

Sounds to me as if your `.classpath` file has been modified. I always recommend to check it in into the source control system (along with the  `.project` and the rest of metadata files of the Eclipse project), taking care just not to include absolute paths.